# Update MySQL with Solaris 11 IPS Package

Tags: mysql, update, solaris

I'm barely new with Solaris OS and there are still a couple of things I definitely don't get it.

I want to replicate a MySQL installation that someone did in the past in a development server we have. Simple: MySQL 5.6.36 running on Solaris 11.3 installed as a IPS package with its SMF services.

I'm testing a with a fresh new install Solaris 11.3. I did a "pkg install database/mysql-56" ([following this simple guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E49624/gnvkd.html)), but the MySQL IPS package installed version is 5.6.25. 
How can I upgrade it to 5.6.36? Why the latest MySQL IPS Package available version is so old (in fact, I was expecting a newer version, and then try to figure out how to downgrade it)? What I'm missing?

Regards!

Comment: You're probably better off downloading it manually & upgrading - https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.6.html#downloads You're at the mercy of the Solaris package maintainers, I'm afraid

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple things that may be going on here (possibly both):

1. In a fresh install, the default package repository is set to http://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/release/ which contains the packages from the initial Solaris 11.3 release in 2015.  To get updates you need to switch to the /support repo, which is only available to customers with a current support contract.  See *[How to Update Oracle Solaris 11 Systems From Oracle Support Repositories](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-admin/o11-018-howto-update-s11-1572261.html)* for instructions.
2. The packages provided with Solaris, like MySQL, default to being updated only as part of an OS update, not individually.  You may be able to unlock them to allow changing versions independently when needed - this is described in *[More Tips for Updating Your Oracle Solaris 11 System from the Oracle Support Repository](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-admin/tips-maintain-s11-sru-1627108.html)* under "Updating an Individual Package" or in *[Relaxing Version Constraints Specified by Constraint Packages](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54739/gmias.html#scrolltoc)*.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't very familiarized with Oracle Support Repository mechanics. Thanks for your clear explanations and useful links!